# Const correct interface for non-mutating function that returns mutable references into data structure

Tags: c++, interfaces, const

I very much want my code to be const correct and I'm struggling to get the following case right.

Say we have a function `F` that takes a data structure `D` and computes an auxiliary data structure `D'`. `F` does not mutate `D`, but the returned data structure `D'` holds non-const pointers to elements in `D`.

`D` could be a directed graph and `F` could compute the dominator tree of `D`. In C++ it would look roughly like this:

```cpp
class Vertex { /* holds pointers to other vertices */ };

class Graph {
public:
    // Interface propagates const-ness, i.e. 
    // begin() and end() return iterators to Vertex const* if Graph is const, 
    // operator[] returns Vertex const* if Graph is const etc.
private:
    std::vector<Vertex*> vertices;
};

class DomTree {
public:
    struct Node {
        Vertex* v; // Pointer to vertices in the original graph
        std::vector<Node*> children; 
    }; 
    // ...
private:
    // To access nodes by their corresponding vertices
    std::unordered_map<Vertex*, Node>;
};

DomTree computeDomTree(Graph& G);       // (*) This?
DomTree computeDomTree(Graph const& G); // (**) Or this?
```

I'm trying to decide if I should have `computeDomTree` take a non-const reference to a `Graph` (*) or a const reference (**).

I think a `const&` parameter makes sense, because `computeDomTree` does not mutate the graph. But then the vertices of the `const` graph could be mutated through the resulting data structure.
Also we would have to cast away `const` in the implementation of `computeDomTree`, which is a huge code smell.

For now I went with the non-const reference parameter, but this also feels wrong when I have a `const` graph and need to compute the dominator tree, I have to cast away const and remember to not mutate the vertices through `DomTree`.

I guess another approach would be to have overloads for `&` and `const&` parameters, but this would require two seperate `DomTree` and `ConstDomTree` classes. Then other function which operate on dominator trees would either need overloads for `DomTree` and `ConstDomTree`, or I need a conversion from `DomTree` to `ConstDomTree` which would result in costly unnecessary reallocations. Let alone the trouble to maintain the two dom-tree classes.

Or should I just ditch const-correctness altogether, accept some `const_cast`'s and hope for the best? Doesn't really seem like a good idea either...

Comment: *"But then the vertices of the const graph could be mutated through the resulting data structure."* -- Passing an object by const-reference does not mean that the object being referred-to is immutable.    The const qualifier *only* applies to the reference and does not affect the semantics of the object in any way.      Indeed, 'const correctness' is not about immutability, merely a way to limit the scope of mutating operations.    (A mutable object might expose `const` methods and be passed as `const` to limit the exposure of its non-const interface, but still be mutated elsewhere).

Comment: @BenCottrell Yes, but it should imply (if you ignore malicious uses of `const_cast`) that the object will not be mutated (directly or indirectly) _through_ the const reference. I.e. if a functions only access to a `Graph` is via a const reference, that function should not mutate the graph. But due to the way I currently implemented `computeDomTree`, the function could compute the dom tree, access the vertices via the `DomTree` object and then mutate the vertices. Since `Graph` owns the vertices, the `Graph` is now mutated, even though the function only ever had a const reference to it.

Comment: Why do the Nodes in your DomTree require a non-const  `Vertex* v`?

Comment: @DocBrown Because there are algorithms which use a `DomTree` to search for vertices with certain properties and then mutate these vertices.

Comment: I am under the impression the problem (or lets say challenge) is more fundamental and should already manifest itself when just looking at `Graph alone`, for example. For the `Graph` class, can you explain how you implemented `begin() const`, returning something like `vector<const Vertex*>::const_iterator`,  without copying all elements of `vertices` from `Vertex *` to `const Vertext *`?

Comment: @DocBrown It is implemented using transform iterators from the range-v3 library. They lazily cast from `Vertex*` to `Vertex const*` on iteration. A simpler version of the problem would perhaps be `std::vector<T /*const-or-not*/ *> computeSmth(std::list<T> /*const-or-not*/ &)`, just that `std::vector<T /*const-or-not*/ *>` is a class type that holds a collection of const or non-const pointers to elements in the list.

Comment: After thinking a while about the case, I am pretty sure you will nee a DomTree and a ConstDomTree, for the same reasons why the standard lib provides `iterator` and `const_iterator`. One can take the point of view that `DomTree` is nothing but a very special iterator for the vertices of a `Graph`. Implementation-wise, I guess DomTree and ConstDomTree can be implemented using some template helper class or base class, like DomTreeBase<class T>, where T is eiter `Vertex *`  or `const Vertex *`. That could help to keep the implementation DRY.

Comment: @DocBrown Thank you for your time and effort. Yes, I guess this is the only way to stay const correct. Thinking about `DomTree` as a kind of iterator definitely makes sense. I thought about having DomTree derive from ConstDomTree so they share most of the implementation and then a DomTree can be implicitly converted to a ConstDomTree without overhead but not the other way around. I will give this a try.